# Fwrite() array of structs to file in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

fwrite() does not match input from array of structs.

Tried: binary files, printing fields of struct elements prior to fwrite.

```
FILE *currentPartition;

    struct FAT {
    char *filename;
    int file_length;
    int blockPtrs[10];
    int current_location;       
    } fat[20];`

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
     {
      printf("Appending fat index: %d\n",i);
      printf("filename: %s\n",fat[i].filename);
      printf("file length: %d\n",fat[i].file_length);

      printf("current location: %d\n",fat[i].current_location);

      fwrite(fat,sizeof(struct FAT),1,currentPartition);}
```

When I later fread, this code does not return what i originally fwrote into the file.

Comment: You could have a structure alignment problem, in gcc try : -fpack-struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your struct contains a pointer to `filename`, which is an address of data allocated at the time or write. You did not write the string which represents the name, just the pointer to it.

When you read it, your program would read the same pointer, but where does it point to? There is probably no string, or it is at a completely different address. So, you need to make sure that the string is written. The easiest way is to have a `char filename[LEN];` as your struct field, where LEN is a big enough number. Otherwise, you need to write the string separately and then restore it as a separate entity.

Comment: I did not include it, but I am actually assigning the string before. In the end, this works but, it seems that for my first fat[] index, the file_size and filename that I write to the file is not the same as the one I read later on.

For example,
I do: 
fat[0].filename="test";
fat[0].file_size=3;
But when I fread, I get that the filename at that index is NULL and my filesize is 768. 
Any thoughts ?

Comment: there is not enough info in your sample to analyze the write/read sequence. You should probably ask another question with more information.  Most likely you have some memory corruption which causes the size differences.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help. I switched to fprintf-ing each struct element individually and it ended up working.